# Situar elemento debajo de listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, layout

Necesito colocar un elemento debajo de un listview.

Hasta ahora tengo un Linearlayout que contiene unos spinner que está situado sobre un listview. Al estar en un LinearLayout, este se queda fijo y debajo tengo un Listview el cual se mueve abajo y arriba. Hasta ahora está así:

[image: Imagen 1]
[image: Imagen 2]

Lo que quiero ahora es, poner el LinearLayout que contiene los spinner para que aparezca debajo del listview pero que no esté fijo como está ahora, sino que aparezca debajo del último elemento del listview.

Esto es como tengo ahora el layout de esta actividad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="net.pablo.android.app.acciones_lora_activity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/capaMedida"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background"
    >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerComp1"
            android:entries="@array/compuertasLora"
            android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown">
            </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerC1"
            android:entries="@array/accionesMedidaLora"
            android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown">

        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>



    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerComp2"
            android:entries="@array/compuertasLora"
            android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown">
            </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerC2"
            android:entries="@array/accionesMedidaLora"
            android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown">

        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerComp3"
            android:entries="@array/compuertasLora"
            android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown">
            </Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerC3"
            android:entries="@array/accionesMedidaLora"
            android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown">

        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_accionesMedida"
            android:text="Enviar accion"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/espacio"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_accionesMedida"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Acciones a medida"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mi_lista"
    android:layout_below="@+id/capaMedida"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres que al hacer scroll lo ultimo que sea sea el LinearLayout?

Comment: eso es, primero que se muestre el listview y al bajar, debajo del último elemento que se muestre ese linearlayout que tiene los spinner. Como si el último elemento del listview fuese ese linearlayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe un metodo llamado [`ListView#addFooterView(view)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)) que agrega una vista al final de la lista.

Crea un archivo xml en la carpeta `layout` y agrega el contenido de la vista que quieres agregar al final. Entonces cuando inicializes la lista, inflas la vista y la agregas con el metodo `addFooterView`:

```
// inflamos la vista que queremos al final
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.id_vista, null);

// la agregamos a lista
miListView.addFooterView(footer);

// agregamos los eventos que necesitemos al footer...
// footer.findViewById(R.id.idSpinner).setOnClickListener
```

Comment: entonces, si no lo entiendo mal, en este layout tendría solamente el listview y en otro el linearlayout que contiene a los spinner?

Comment: Exacto. Eso seria lo mas conveniente.

Comment: voy a probarlo, ahora mi duda es si podré hacer referencia a los spinner igual que hasta ahora al estar en otro layout

Comment: Si pero ahora tendrias que utilizar la variable `footer` como esta en mi ejemplo para poder buscar los elementos de la vista donde tienes los spinners.

Comment: perfect, voy a ver si lo consigo hacer, muchas gracias =)

Comment: una pregunta, he metido el código en otro layout llamado ordenMedida.xml pero no me queda claro ahora que es R.id.id_vista el layout general que contiene todo? porque el nombre del archivo xml no es y si le pongo el id del relativeLayout que es la raiz me da error

Comment: Cometi un error. En vez de `R.id.mi_vista`, es `R.layout.mi_vista` que en tu caso seria `R.layout.ordenMedida`

Comment: Funcionando!!! muchas gracias =)